# Unable to install missing video and audio plugins

Tags: apt, sound, software-installation, package-management

When I try to install missing plugins on terminal, the following output appears:

```
arif@arif-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for arif: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
arif@arif-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
arif@arif-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: What ubuntu release is this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the software center -> edit -> software sources and check all boxes. I think the one you need is multiverse, but just to be sure, enable all.
Then do `sudo apt-get update` (unless it updates automatically), now the package should be able to be located.

Comment: This is correct. Why has it been downvoted? You have to enable multiverse to have access to `-restricted-extra`.

Answer (score -1):

`purge` command is used to remove the component with all its dependencies. If you want to install the package use the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: No, `purge` delete a component with *all the configuration files* (`remove` did not touch configuration files). Both delete the *automatically installed* dependencies that are no more referenced --- none touch manually installed dependencies.